# Деревья ставятся под углом в Unity

Tags: unity3d, terrain

День добрый всем. Я хотел сделать карту, сделал Terrain, сделал модели деревьев, всё сделал, чтобы они ставились. Но есть проблема. Они ставятся под углом и как бы я их не наклонял они стоят под углом. В самой модели угол наклона менял, не помогло. Может кто-нибудь помочь?[image: Вот, как это выглядит]